# Matlab: insert multiple elements at specified positions

Tags: arrays, matlab, insert

I have a large array `A`, in which I wish to insert values at specific positions. These values and positions are stored in array `B`. Can I execute this assignment using indexing, i.e. without resorting to a `for`-loop or `arrayfun`?

Example:

```
% target array
A = [NaN NaN;
     NaN NaN];

%    r c value
B = [1 1 17; 
     1 2 13; 
     2 2 21];

% ?? Mystery operation ??

% Desired result:

A = [17   13;
     NaN  21];
```

Comment: Probably want to use a [sparse matrix](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) ... `A = sparse(B(:,1), B(:,2), B(:,3),[],[],NaN)`

Comment: You will probably want to specify the number of rows and columns in the 4th and 5th arguments passed to `sparse()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Another approach might be with the use of *[linear indices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511)*:

```
% Define data
A = [NaN NaN; 
     NaN NaN];
B = [1 1 17; 
     1 2 13; 
     2 2 21];
% Create linear indices for matrix A, with rows from B(:, 1) and columns from B(:, 2)
indices = sub2ind(size(A), B(:, 1), B(:, 2));
% Replace the data in A with values from B(:, 3)
A(indices) = B(:, 3);
```

Comment: Great, this is the proper solution. Readable and elegant, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a vectorize solution:

```
accumarray(B(:,1:2),B(:,3),[],[],NaN)
```

referring to documentation of [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)  we can use signature `accumarray(subs,val,sz,fun,fillval)` that first two arguments are `subs= [row and column indices]` and  `val=value of matrix` and 5th argument `fillval`:

> fills all elements of A that are not referred to by any subscript in `subs` with the scalar value `fillval`

so we use `NaN` for the 5th argument.

or you can use signature `accumarray(subs,val,sz,fun,fillval,issparse)` if you want to create sparse matrix.